# Crear una consulta SQL

Tags: sql

Hola quiero crear una consulta ala base de datos SQL en la que me dé como resultado que artículos no  tienen asignados una bodega por ejemplo bodega 1.

```
Select * from e.articulo_bodega where bodega="07";
```

De esa forma me muestra las que si tienen asignados la bodega 07 pero quisiera ver lo que no lo tienen asignados.

Comment: Procura siempre indicar en qué BD estás haciendo cosas. Lo otro: para preguntas de bases de datos es sano incluir algunos datos de prueba en las tablas que usas y el resultado esperado. EN esta en particular es viable responder sin eso, pero es la excepción :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En sql el operador para comprobar que dos elementos sean distintos es <>. Tu consulta sería algo así:

```
Select * from e.articulo_bodega where bodega <> "07";
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias un abrazo.